# how to get web api in nodejs (without lib)

Tags: node.js, document

I am making a module that converts html to json in node environment. I would like to know how to access web browser api from node. How can I access document object with nodejs only without libraries such as cheerio and jsdom?
(I used Google Translate, sorry)

Comment: If you want to parse DOM so you can manipulate it like what you can do in browser, such as `document.querySelector`, you have to implement DOM by your own, cuz NodeJS remove browser related API.

Comment: @nouvist — In the same way that a boat doesn't remove wheels, Node.js doesn't remove those APIs, it never had them to begin with.

Comment: @Quentin ouh i see, cuz they using v8, not chrome. right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does not have built-in support for rendering HTML documents.

It doesn't execute JavaScript that it extracts from `<script>` elements inside an HTML document.

It has no native `document` object.

If you want one you either need to build it yourself or use a third-party library.